# pass multiple textbox values to controller Code igniter

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am newbie in [Codeigniter](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter) so I don't know how to do this.
Actually my view page has five rows which I generated through for loop in which each row contain two select boxes and two input boxes. I don't know how to get these values first in **jQuery** and then pass into controller. Actually I know how to grab values from a simple textboxes but because I generate them in a loop and give them a separate id, so I don't know how to get the values in jQuery and then pass to the controller.

This is my view

```
       <tr>
        <th>Category:</th>
    <th>Items:</th>
       <th>Selling Price:</th>
        <th>quantity:</th>

</tr>

    <?php for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {

    ?>
    <tr> //Categories
<td><?php echo form_dropdown('cat_id', $records2, '#', 
        "id='category_".$i."'  onchange='getItems(this.value,".$i.")' ");?>
                        </td>
          <!-- Items -->

  <td>form_dropdown('item_id', $records3, '#', "id='items_".$i."'"); ?> </td>
    <!-- end of Items -->



    <td> <?php echo form_input($price); ?></td>

<td><?php echo form_input($quantity); }?></td>
```

The item options is based on the categories selection, means if I select some option from categories, then the items against categories show in a second select box.

Here is my Javascript for functionality of top  two select boxes

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

function getItems(category_id,index) {

       $("#items_" + index + " > option").remove(); 

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "stockInController/get_Items/"+category_id, 
        success: function(items) 
        {
            $.each(items,function(item_id,item_name) 
            {
                var opt = $('<option />'); 
                opt.val(item_id);
                opt.text(item_name);
                $('#items_'+ index).append(opt); 
            });
        }

    });
}
 </script>
```

Now the problem is here; I want to get the values from all the rows and then pass into controller.
This is the javascript for catching and then sending values to controller

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
 $('#btns').click(function() { //  $("#form").serialize()
```

Here, I am not doing right, first I don't know how to get values of item and categories here and then the other thing is how to be able to get multiple textbox values because there are five rows, and the textvalues in which values are filled are to be sent

```
var item_id = $('#items').val();   
var item_id = $('#items').val();


var price = $('#price').val();
var quantity = $('#quantity').val();




var form_data = {
        cat_id: $('#cat_id').val(),

        quantity: $('#quantity').val(),
        item_id: $('#items').val(),




};


$.ajax({
    url: "<?php echo site_url('salesController/addSales'); ?>",
    type: 'POST',
    data: form_data,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(msg) {
        if(msg.res == 1)
        {

            alert("true");
        }
        else{
            alert("false");          
          }


    }
});

return false;
    });


</script>
```

Here is my controller and I don't know to get multiple values here also.
Here is the code of what I am doing, I know I am wrong, but I don't know how to make it right

```
       $data = array(
            'cat_id' => $this->input->post('cat_id'),

            'item_id' => $this->input->post('item_id'),
            'price' => $this->input->post('sales_date'),
            'quantity' => $this->input->post('sales_bill_no'),

            );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, set the `name` of your `input` and `select` elements like this `cat_ids[]`, `item_ids[]`, `prices[]` and `quantities[]`. Note the `[]` at the end of these name (I have changed the name to make it in plural-form, this is just a name convention :) ).

In the controllers `$this->input->post('cat_ids')` will return an **array** named `cat_id` and contains all your ids, this is the same for `$this->input->post('item_ids')`, `$this->input->post('prices')`, ... You can use a `for` loop like this to traverse through all posted values:

```php
for($i = 0; $i < count($data['cat_id']); $i++)
{
    $yourItem = array (
        'cat_id' => $data['cat_id'][$i],
        'item_id' => $data['item_id'][$i],
        'price' => $data['price'][$i],
        'quantity' => $data['quantity'][$i],
    );
}
```

To send the form data in Ajax uses jQuery you can set your `form_data=$('your-form-id').serialize();` instead of building its value by your hand :)

Comment: ok i'll try this and then reply you but what about the jquery function here   var item_id = $('#items').val();     here i am doing wrong because my item id is constantly changing and going to 0 -4 like this item_0, item_1 .. how to  i grab values this in jquery ?

Comment: I have update my answer with a modification in how to get the form data :)

Comment: thanksssssssss it works .. u r genious ..... all  is working except quantity and price is not going into the database.. as u said i have changed the name of price and quantity textboxes to price[] and quantity[].. and  i am getting value in controller like that of price and quantity 'price' => $this->input->post('price').. am i doing right .. i think i have to changed this to  'price' => $this->input->post('price[]') am i right ?

Comment: ok ok i get it ..  i know what was going wrong,,, thank you man .. u have done a lot for me .. god blessed you

Comment: If your input element name is `price` and `quantity` and you have to use `$this->input->post('price')` and `$this->input->post('quantity')` in your controller. I found that you have to modify your `echo form_input($price)` and `echo form_input($quantity)` to include the name.

Comment: yeah yeah i know that .. actually i misspell it ... thankss for you time .. thanks to you ..

Answer (score 1):

dont know about php but maybe you could send multiple params in request like:

```
   var cat_id = $('#cat_id').val();
   var quantity = $('#quantity').val();
   var item_id = $('#items').val();

$.ajax({
url: "<?php echo site_url('salesController/addSales'); ?>",
type: 'POST',
data: 'cat_id='+cat_id+'&quantity='+quantity+'&item_id='+item_id,
success: function() {

}
```

});

in groovy I would parse them like

```
params.cat_id
params.item_id etc...
```

maybe this helps you or someone to help you