# sending multiple form data form to controller in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a table list of data and have a input box beside them 
example :

Name   M/F

name1  ***_*___**

name2  ***_*___**

i only set 1 form to send data from that form inside a table and send it to controller
in controller when i using this to receive the form data

```
$data_done['sex']   = $this->input->post('sex');
```

this only received the first data only.. how can i get all the data in controller? 
FYI that table data is a loop from DB..
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Change the `name` of your `input` to `name[]`, `sex[]`, `name1_[]`, ... instead. You can see my answer in another question here for more details [pass multiple textbox values to controller Code igniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14414621/pass-multiple-textbox-values-to-controller-code-igniter/14414703#14414703)